# Google Custom Search Element: Styling Ads

Tags: adsense, google-custom-search

I added a Google Custom Search Element to my website. I already modified the look and feel of the CSE to my website, but I can't modify the look of the **ads element** since it is inside an **Iframe**.

Does anybody know how to set-up the style of the ads Iframe? I want do put in a background color and change the font.

Thanks!

Comment: It might be against Terms of Service

Comment: Also, styling into an iframe is subject to the same origin/domain policy.  If it's not on your domain, the browser will restrict it because of possible page hijacking.

Answer (score 1):

This feature seems to be available only for [Google Site Search](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products_gss.html) customers. If you are one, you'll be able to recieve your search results as an XML feed, and apply a presentation layer on the raw data. All the details on how to do this are available [at the official Google Custom Search site](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/snippets).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this api for AdSence search - https://developers.google.com/custom-search-ads/docs/implementation-guide?hl=en , but you can't make ads view like search results.